# Can I run both wordpress website and non-wordpress website on same domain, what do i do with the Index.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing

So ,
Can I run both wordpress website and non-wordpress website on same domain ?
There are no file conflicts from the 2 scripts ,so they both go fine on same domain.
My main problem is with the index file: i will keep the non-wordpress index.php file ,and have to do something with the wordpress index.php file ...

**Where do i put index.php from wordpress,in order for it to work ?
Other script works perfect because it has it's index.php file .
Can i add it in the wordpress template's files ?**

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You will get problems if you apply permalinks. I suggest you put one of the systems in a folder like: `example.com` has your system and `example.com/blog` has wordpress.

Comment: Permalinks are different ,this would be the only problem ? Is there a way to make them work together ?

Comment: It would be the biggest problem. Also think about maintainability, 2 systems in one folder is harder to maintain. It can give SEO problems.

Comment: The non-wordpress script is little ,and i will keep it for only few months . I need to keep wordpress on the same domain ,because it will stay there .

Comment: Then flip my solution. Move your script to `example.com/temp-script/` and put it there.